# Cakephp HABTM saving -.-

Tags: cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm googling high and low on this. I'm not sure where i went wrong cause I don't get any errors.

i have 3 tables:

MOVIES - id, title, genre, etc

GENRES - id, genre

GENRES_MOVIES - movie_id, genre_id

Movie model:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
'Genre' => array(
        'className' => 'Genre',
        'joinTable' => 'genres_movies',
        'foreignKey' => 'movie_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'genre_id'
    )
);
```

View:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Movie', array('controller' => 'movies', 'action' => 'add', 'type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->input('title');
echo $this->Form->input('description', array('type' => 'textarea');
echo $this->Form->input('imdb_url');
echo $this->Form->year('release_year', 1900, date('Y'));
echo $this->Form->input('length', array('type' => 'number'));
echo $this->Form->input('genre', array('type'=>'select', 'multiple'=>'checkbox', 'options'=> $genres));
echo $this->Form->input('image', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->button('Submit');
```

MoviesController:

```
    public function add()
        {
        /* for populating checkbox */
        $this->set('genres', $this->Movie->Genre->find('list', array('fields' => array('Genre.id', 'Genre.genre'))));

        if($this->request->is('post'))
            {
             $data_movie = array(
             'title' => $this->request->data['Movie']['title'],
             'description' => $this->request->data['Movie']['description'],
             'imdb_url' => $this->request->data['Movie']['imdb_url'],
             'release_year' => (int)$this->request->data['Movie']['release_year']['year'],
             'length' => (int)$this->request->data['Movie']['length'],
             'user_id' => (int)$this->Auth->user('id')
            );

             $data_genre = array('Genre' => array());
             foreach($this->request->data['Movie']['genre'] as $genre)
                array_push($data_genre['Genre'], (int)$genre);

             $data = array('Movie' => $data_movie, 'Genre' => $data_genre);
             $this->Movie->create(); 

                     if($this->Movie->save($data)   
                    {
                    echo 'success';
                }
            } 

        }
```

So, why did I bother setting up data manually for saving in the movieController, it is because the tutorials are telling me data should be organised like it is now (before that it looked a little different.. so i tried and this is what i have now (it looks ok to me)
http://s10.postimg.org/ikewszo95/Untitled_1.jpg

you can see the form here http://marko-stimac.iz.hr/temp/movies/movies/add (although submit wont work, i guess it is because of the Auth component not letting non-registered users)

hm any help would be greeatly appreciated :)

EDIT - updated controller

```
public function add()
    {
           $this->set('genres', $this->Movie->Genre->find('list', array('fields' => array('Genre.id', 'Genre.genre'))));

    if($this->request->is('post'))
        {
            ($this->Movie->saveAssociated($this->request->data))    
                {
              $this->redirect('/');
              $this->Session->setFlash('Success.');
            }
        } 

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't modify the data, that is, get rid of these lines

```
$data_genre = array('Genre' => array());
foreach($this->request->data['Movie']['genre'] as $genre)
            array_push($data_genre['Genre'], (int)$genre);
$data = array('Movie' => $data_movie, 'Genre' => $data_genre);
$this->Movie->create();
```

And save your data using

```
if ($this->Movie->saveAssociated($this->request->data) {
    ...
```

**EDIT**

Modify your form, change this

```
echo $this->Form->input('genre', array('type'=>'select', 'multiple'=>'checkbox', 'options'=> $genres));
```

to this

```
echo $this->Form->input('Genre', array('type'=>'select', 'multiple'=>'checkbox', 'options'=> $genres));
```

Comment: it doesnt work.. and this is what i get with debug($this->request->data) http://s22.postimg.org/j2i8mpvlt/Untitled_2.jpg

Comment: Why is it failing? did you check validationErrors?

Comment: i dont even have anything to validate. there is no $validate, nor function beforeSave in Movie model :/

Comment: Paste again your controller, including the modifications I told you to include

Comment: ok i did, it is a stripped controller, nothing else. but, im not sure how could data be saved, especially since a user uploads a file and its image name should be saved.

Comment: Success! (with also a little manual tweaking in controller). thank you for bothering :)